# How to approach a employer about grad school?

Tags: career-development, research, graduate

I want to work for a sociological research institution as a scientific programmer after college. How I will go about that is for another question.

I would like to go to grad school for a non-sociology degree ( Computer Engineering ) and use what I learn in order to be a better scientific programmer for computational-based sociology. How can I make a plan in order to proceed to convince my future employer to pay for grad school in a different field?

Comment: Most companies that I know of offer tuition reimbursement, however this option is usually only open to employees who are part of the company for some time, not for new hires.

Comment: Whether a company will offer you a bursary tends to be more about company policy than your ability to say the right words (although, if there are "right words" it would largely be about convincing them that you're passionate about the field and the company and that you'd be skilled at it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you should check the company policy for tuition reimbursement, if you work there.
If you are not employed in any way at that company, and cannot get a employee handbook, your only option is to inquire about that company`s policy during one of your interviews.

Comment: Note that many companies indicate they will only reimburse tuition for programs that promote learning required by the company.  If you are hiring on to program, you need to read your company's policy carefully to see if they will reimburse a Sociology degree.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot plan to make someone else do something.  Instead look over the employee benefits with a careful eye to see if they already support furthering one's education.

Some employers do so only for a degree that specifically can be used by the company.  A few don't place a restriction on what you may study.  Most require that your company be notified and that they review your request before deciding if they will reimburse expenses.

Some employers will place restrictions on the reimbursement, requiring you to pay back the reimbursement if you don't maintain a sufficient amount of time at the company after receiving it.  This is a common policy to prevent people from leaving immediately after a company helps them obtain the new degrees.